# Expo packager constantly rebuilding when finished

Tags: react-native, expo

when running `expo start` my packager starts looping and rebuilding the app. On my android device, the downloading package reaches 100% and then start reloading the percentage.
It worked until lately and now I can't find a solution and bring up the app

The packager log looks like this:

```
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 56ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 90ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 93ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 62ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 62ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 82ms.
```

Comment: Could you try `expo start -c`?

Comment: I did already. I resolved it by restarting my mobile